# Trouble setting Cisco switch boot image

Tags: cisco

I am trying to upgrade a cisco 3850f-e from 16.09.04 to 16.12.10a. I got the 16.12.10a bin in flash and set it as the boot image. Looked good so I did `write memory`.  After a `reload` it still booted using 16.09.04. I did `show boot` and got the following. Looks like my boot variable is wonky. How cany I fix?

````
Tue Dec 19 2023 03:28:31 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
===================================================================================
#show boot
---------------------------
Switch 1
---------------------------
Current Boot Variables:
BOOT variable = flash:cat3k_caa-universalk9.16.12.10a.SPA.bin;flash:cat3k_caa-universalk9.16.09.04.SPA.bin;flash:/cat3k_caa-universalk9.16.12.10a.SPA.bin;
Boot Variables on next reload:
BOOT variable = flash:cat3k_caa-universalk9.16.12.10a.SPA.bin;flash:cat3k_caa-universalk9.16.09.04.SPA.bin;flash:/cat3k_caa-universalk9.16.12.10a.SPA.bin;
Manual Boot = no
Enable Break = no
Boot Mode = DEVICE
iPXE Timeout = 0```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'show run' command to see the current configuration of the switch. It should show the boot configuration lines in it. From the configuration terminal, negate the incorrect commands and then put in the correct ones. In this situation, you should have 2 boot variables: the new one listed first and the older version listed second. This is so it can try the second, older firmware if the new one fails to boot properly.

In my experience, you do no need the slash (/) character in the boot variable path, but some platforms do use it in some cases.

As always, be very careful to spell the file names correctly, and watch the boot process on the serial console if possible so you can see why it did not boot the new file.

You can also move from Bundle mode to Install mode, which is the preferred method for 3850 series switches.

[Cisco Instructions for Bundle and Install modes](https://content.cisco.com/chapter.sjs?uri=/searchable/chapter/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/Denali_16-1/ConfigExamples_Technotes/Config_Examples/Misc/qos/m_install_vs_bundle.html.xml)

[Youtube video for change from Bundle to Install mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsYE-ZXtHO4)